# Problem with binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients

So here is the problem:

> Find the constant term in the expansion of (x-(2/x))^2 ·（x^2 +(2/x))^3

I understand I can just use my calculator to figure out the answer, but is there any simple way to solve that ? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't multiplication simple enough?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's quite a fun way to check your answer : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-2%2Fx)%5E2(x%5E2%2B2%2Fx)%5E3

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal which might be convenient.

- At first note that it is helpful to have the first
  rows of *[Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)* in mind at least $1;\quad 1,1;\quad 1,2,1;\quad 1,3,3,1$.
- So, we already know $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$.

Here we also use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ just for ease of notation.

> Having these prerequisits close at hand, we can calculate
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^0]&\left(x-\frac{2}{x}\right)^2\left(x^2+\frac{2}{x}\right)^3\\
> &=[x^0]\left(x^2-4+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)\left(x^6+6x^3+12+\frac{8}{x^3}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-48}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial theorem twice and expand the binomials.
- In (2) we take a closer look at the left-hand factor $\left(x^2-4+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)$.

  - Looking at $x^2$ we need a term with $\frac{1}{x^2}$ at the right-hand factor, which don't exist.
  - Looking at $-4$ we see we can take $12$ at the right-hand factor, which gives $-48$.
  - Looking at $\frac{4}{x^2}$ we need a term with $x^2$ at the right-hand factor, which don't exist.
  - No further considerations are necessary.